# Very large matrix vector product

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vector, matrix-multiplication

I have a large symmetric matrix `A` of dimensions `(N, N)` (`N` is about twenty million), and for sure I cannot store this matrix (50% components of `A` are zeros).

But every component `A[i, j]` is explicitly known: `A[i, j] = f(i, j)`. For example `A[i, j] = cos(i)*cos(j)`.

I need to multiply this matrix with a vector of length `N`. What is "doable" way to do that on a machine of 64 cores, 128GB of RAM?

Comment: I believe [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is the way to manipulate a giant matrix in python. Take a look on it

Comment: Sounds like a perfect application for a sparse linear algebra library (scipy.sparse or pysparse)

Comment: Note: the specific example `A` you've chosen factors nicely into the product of an N-by-1 matrix and a 1-by-N matrix. Switching the order of multiplication to multiply the 1-by-N factor by the vector and then multiply the N-by-1 factor by the result produces a very space- and time-efficient calculation. This is probably just a feature of the example, but if it happens with your real data too, be sure to take advantage of it.

Comment: @alonisser: numpy supports dense matrices, which wouldn't be a very useful data structure for a large, symmetric, and mostly zero matrix

Comment: @talonmies . so scipy.sparse should be the way to go, as you already wrote

Comment: can you tell a bit more about your f(i,j) in the real case? Maybe there are properties of that function that can be (ab)used to speed up or simplify the calculations.

Comment: I don't think sparse structure is useful. 50% of 20 million x 20 million still too large to handle.

Comment: This might be a silly question, in fact is certainly is, but cos(i)cos(j) repeats and, since A is symmetric, there are some tricks that you should be able to use. Additionally - what do you want as an output? Are you hoping to get a new, completed, matrix? I think you might be well served taking the problem over to MathOverflow as I think your best bet will be to find a way to simplify the problem rather than try to multiply it as it currently stands.

Comment: `multiply by N` - a dot product the reduces the dimensions, or broadcasted? i.e. `cos(i)*cos(j)*N(i)->M(i,j)` or `sum(i)(...)->M(j)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a way to compute elements of matrix on the fly there is no need to store whole matrix in memory. Also each element of result vector in independent of each other so you can run as many parallel workers as you want.

The only optimization of algorithm I can think of is take into consideration that `f(i, j) = cos(i)*cos(j)` is symmetric function (`f(i, j) = f(j, i)`). But that's if this is your real function.

Also check [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [Cython](http://cython.org/) for much faster computations in Python as pure Python can be a little slow for this kind of job.

Comment: Yes, my real function is symmetric. But I don't understand what do you mean about optimization here.

Comment: I mean that you don't have to compute f(i, j) and f(j, i) separately. It is enough to get value once. So instead of `N * N` computations you can get `N*(N+1)/2`.